# TypeError - invalid login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules, nodemailer

I wrote some code to implement nodemailer in my nodejs application to send mails.

i wrote this code:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

/* GET contact page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("contact", { title: "Contact" });
});

router.post("/send", function (req, res, next) {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "MyEmailHere",
      pass: "password",
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: "MyEmailHere",
    to: "myOtherEmailId",
    subject: "Website Submission",
    text:
      "You have a new submission with the following details...Name: " +
      req.body.name +
      " Email: " +
      req.body.email +
      " Message: " +
      req.body.message,
    html:
      "<p> You got a new submission with the following details...</p><ul></ul><li>Name: " +
      req.body.name +
      "</li><li>Email: " +
      req.body.email +
      "</li><li>Message: " +
      req.body.message +
      "</li></ul>",
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      console.log("Message Sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But I get an error saying: "Username and password not accepted." Am i supposed to use my real password? Does nodemailer also support Yahoomail besides Gmail? I am still learning and in dev mode by the way. A little help?

Comment: Use your real credentials.

Comment: @ArielAlvarado Ok. But does node mailer support Yahoomail or only Gmail? I can't seem to remember my Gmail password but i do remember that of yahoomail. I am asking this just in case i decide to change the service: Gmail to service: Yahoomail.

Comment: I used my real Gmail credentials as you said BUT i am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked flawlessly when I entered my own information correctly and turned on 'less secure apps', please try it this way

**NOTE (critical):** make sure the 'less secure apps' option is turned on
*(If you don't know how to open, you can [visit here](https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/))*

**NOTE:** Make sure 2-step verification is turned off

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const myGmailAccount = {
  mail: 'your_gmail_address', // MAIL
  passw: 'your_gmail_password', // PASSW
};

/* GET contact page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("contact", { title: "Contact" });
});

router.post("/send", function (req, res, next) {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
      user: myGmailAccount.mail,
      pass: myGmailAccount.passw,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: myGmailAccount.mail,
    to: 'emintayfur@icloud.com', // recipient mail
    subject: "Website Submission",
    text:
      "You have a new submission with the following details...Name: " +
      req.body.name +
      " Email: " +
      req.body.email +
      " Message: " +
      req.body.message,
    html:
      "<p> You got a new submission with the following details...</p><ul></ul><li>Name: " +
      req.body.name +
      "</li><li>Email: " +
      req.body.email +
      "</li><li>Message: " +
      req.body.message +
      "</li></ul>",
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      console.log("Message Sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** you need to enter your real information and **I recommend you to read this text.**

> Even though Gmail is the fastest way to get started with sending
> emails, it is by no means a preferable solution unless you are using
> OAuth2 authentication. Gmail expects the user to be an actual user not
> a robot so it runs a lot of heuristics for every login attempt and
> blocks anything that looks suspicious to defend the user from account
> hijacking attempts. For example you might run into trouble if your
> server is in another geographical location – everything works in your
> dev machine but messages are blocked in production.

> Additionally Gmail has came up with the concept of “Less Secure” apps which is
> basically
> anyone who uses plain password to login to Gmail, so you might end up
> in a situation where one username can send mail (support for “less
> secure” apps is enabled) but other is blocked (support for “less
> secure” apps is disabled). You can configure your Gmail account to
> allow less secure apps here. When using this method make sure to also
> enable the required functionality by completing the “Captcha Enable”
> challenge. Without this, less secure connections probably would not
> work.

**And make sure the 'less secure apps' option is turned on**
If you don't know how to open, you can [visit here](https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/)

For more information I suggest you to review [this page](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)

Comment: It is still not working. I changed my Gmail password to a new one, logged in after that smoothly. i used the new password in the code and i am still getting the same error. I am confused.